# Android Studio Two Buttons to Two Pages

Tags: java, android, button

Good morning,

Quick coding inquiry I'd like to put forth.

I've gotten an assignment to produce an application on Android Studio that has two buttons that should each load new pages when clicked.

The chapter from our books explains how to do this with one button, but I assume there might be a different set up with two buttons?

Anyway, this is only the second assignment in our class so I'm not very far in understanding how all of this works; that and the class is an Independent Study course so I'm teaching myself. Not always the easiest thing.

Anyway, here's what I do have:

`MainActivity.java`

```java
package com.example.thelatestmusicscene;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicNewsOne.class));
            }
        });

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicNewsTwo.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I believe this is the only file that's relevant to my problem but I can post the others if you need to see them too.

The first button functions perfectly but when I try to use the second button the app stops working. I've seen a few explanations online, but the few I've found about loading other pages gives me a bunch of errors in my code.

Note: This is how we were shown to do it from the book, but I'm all for alternative methods.

Everything else for this application is done, it's just this linking to the second java page I'm faltering on. If you know a better way to lay out the code I'm all ears or if you could link me to a resource that could teach me, I'd be grateful.

OK, this is going to be the confusing part. When I downloaded Android Studio for the class I could never get any of the emulators to run. This was a problem I also posted, which as of today, has still not received an answer. If you have a solution to that or want to see those details of what I’ve tried, go here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1394568/android-studio-and-haxm-installation

Ultimately, I could write code, but I couldn’t test it. However, I found a way to run the apps on my own smartphone to test if they’re functioning. Letting Android Studio build the APK file and then letting my phone run the app.
Now…as for errors. There are none. Android Studio isn’t coming back with any. As far as it's concerned, everything is fine. When I load the application on my phone and I click the second button, the application closes, and I get “Unfortunately, nameOfApp has stopped.”

And that’s where I find myself.

Here’s the XML (I assume you mean the AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.thelatestmusicscene">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MusicNewsTwo">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MusicNewsOne" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I've got to get some sleep now but I'll try retrieving a crash report from my phone today if I can.

Comment: Please share the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: Hi, please share stack trace of the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother your MainActivity.java file have correct code.
Kindly check button name in xml and java file, and check your manifest file either MusicNewsTwo added as activity.

And be sure you have both java and xml file in correct place.

Answer (score 0):

**Few notes**

- You may need to provide the crash's log/stacktrace/message (for us to know what's the solution for it)
- You may also need to provide us the layout or the `.xml` file

**What could possibly went wrong**

One of the common problems encountered:

Assuming you have only copied it from your class, you might have encountered the error saying that your `MusicNewsTwo.class` is not declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, do this:

**What could be the possible solution**

```java
<application
   android:label="Example APp"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

   <activity
      android:name="package.path.to.MusicNewsOne">

      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <!--  Add this activity if missing -->
   <activity
      android:name="package.path.to.MusicNewsTwo"/>
</application>
```

I will update my answer so as long as you take into consideration the ***Few notes*** section of my answer, otherwise if I got your answer write already with this one, comment out.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem within my phone itself. Turns out it was a permission error for downloading 3rd party apps; my code was actually perfect. Thanks for all the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `IDs` of the `views` in the `layout : "activity_main"` are different than the ones you are using in the `MainActivity.java` file

Answer (score -1):

> Bro there are two ways to do this, start a new Activity like you are doing, and other is By Using one activity you can post   the fragments on the same activity as much as you want i.e 1 ,2 3 and so on.[here is the link for fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments), but you are very much biggner ill suggest you to start with the actitvity and learn about the Activity life cycle. [you can find here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) . moreover tell me what the error you are getting, To find the error see a the bottom of android studio the option (Logcat) click on it . and see the error and past it in the comment.